# Back button behaviour on the App

Tags: feature-request, android-app

The <kbd>Back</kbd> button on the Android app doesn't behave as expected.

If I'm scrolling through the questions list on Stack Overflow, then I apply a filter say, for [android](/questions/tagged/android) questions, and then I open one of these questions and read through it and then I want to exit back to the list, pressing the <kbd>Back</kbd> button doesn't take me back to the filtered list where I was before.

Instead, it opens back the list of available tags to choose from, and then I have to scroll through the whole list of questions again to find where I was, and that's not as convenient as it could be.